Checking the sign value of the derivatives of a complicated function
Consider the following function:
e[w_] := 1/(2 w (w + a i W) (1 + a i w W)) (2 w^2 + 2 a i w^3 W + a^2 i^2 (-1 + 2 w^2) W^2 - \[Sqrt](a i W (4 (i + lambda) w^3 + 4 a i w^2 (1 + 2 i + 2 lambda + (i + lambda) w^2) W + 4 a^2 i^2 w (1 + i + lambda + 2 (i + lambda) w^2) W^2 + a^3 i^3 (1 + 4 (i + lambda) w^2) W^3)))

I'm trying to do two things. First, I would like to verify whether $e$ is an increasing and concave function of $w$ under the assumption of $a \in [0,1]$, $i \in [0,1]$, $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $w>0$, $W>0$. That is, $\frac{\partial e}{\partial w}>0$, $\frac{\partial^2 e}{\partial w^2}<0$.
Here is my code for this:
Clear["Global`*"]; 
e[w_]:= 1/(2 w (w + a i W) (1 + a i w W)) (2 w^2 + 2 a i w^3 W + a^2 i^2 (-1 + 2 w^2) W^2 - \[Sqrt](a i W (4 (i + lambda) w^3 + 4 a i w^2 (1 + 2 i + 2 lambda + (i + lambda) w^2) W + 4 a^2 i^2 w (1 + i + lambda + 2 (i + lambda) w^2) W^2 + a^3 i^3 (1 + 4 (i + lambda) w^2) W^3)));
Assuming[a > 0 && a < 1 && i > 0 && i < 1 && lambda > 0 && lambda < 1 && w > 0 && W > 0, FullSimplify@Reduce[e'[w] > 0]]
Assuming[a > 0 && a < 1 && i > 0 && i < 1 && lambda > 0 && lambda < 1 && w > 0 && W > 0, FullSimplify@Reduce[e''[w] < 0]]

Second, I would like to find $w$ that solves
$$\frac{\partial e}{\partial w}=\frac{e}{w}$$
Here is my code for this:
Assuming[a > 0 && a < 1 && i > 0 && i < 1 && lambda > 0 && lambda < 1 && w > 0 && W > 0, FullSimplify@Solve[e'[w] == e[w]/w, w]]

These codes are running forever. Any help please?

Which is running forever, the solver or the simplifier?

@MichaelE2, I guess it is the solver.

@ppp Function e[w] only depends on two (not four!) parameters a i W and i+lambda

@Ulrich Neumann, thanks, your finding that it only depends on two parameters is very useful!

Function e[w]only depends on two parameters a i W and i+lambda
e[w_] := (2 w^2 + 2 a i w^3 W + 
     a^2 i^2 (-1 + 
        2 w^2) W^2 - \[Sqrt](a i W (4 (i + lambda) w^3 + 
          4 a i w^2 (1 + 2 i + 2 lambda + (i + lambda) w^2) W + 
          4 a^2 i^2 w (1 + i + lambda + 2 (i + lambda) w^2) W^2 + 
          a^3 i^3 (1 + 4 (i + lambda) w^2) W^3))) /. {W -> aiw/(a i), 
    lambda -> ip\[Lambda] - i} // Simplify 


Its possible now to plot the regions
RegionPlot3D[e'[w] > 0 , {aiw, 0.1, 10}, {ip\[Lambda], 0.1, 10}, {w, 0.1, 20},Evaluated -> True, PlotLabel -> "e'[w]>0",AxesLabel -> {"a i W", "i+lambda", "w"}]


RegionPlot3D[e''[w] < 0 , {aiw, 0.1, 10}, {ip\[Lambda], 0.1, 10}, {w, 0.1, 20}, Evaluated -> True, PlotLabel -> "e''[w]<0",AxesLabel -> {"a i W", "i+lambda", "w"}]


addendum
second question
cond = Evaluate[e'[w] - e[w]/w];
ContourPlot3D[ cond  , {aiw, 0.1, 10}, {ip\[Lambda], 0.1, 10}, {w,0.1, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"a i W", "i+lambda", "w"},Contours -> { 0} ]


It looks like cond==0can't be fullfilled in this parameterrange!

Ulrich Neumann, thanks! According to the plots, it seems e'>0 for the entire region examined, and e''<0 for only a partial region, is this correct? One problem with this simulation approach is that we cannot claim it as generally applicable since the parameter regions are not exhaustive. Maybe an analytical approach is not possible?

Can you please help with my second question as well? Thank you so much.

@ppp I tried to answer your second question in my modifoed answer

Ulrich Neumann, thanks for the answer to the second question. But I am wondering if there is a way to find the analytical solution for w explicitly?

@ppp If numerical solution in the given parameter range is correct there is no reason to look for an analytical solution anymore I think!

Ulrich Neumann, thanks, but I am ultimately looking for the analytical solution of w as stated in the post...

@ppp perhaps we have to choose another parameter range???

@ppp The condition w e'[w]==e[w] is an expression with a Sqrt term.  Eliminating this Sqrt by squaring you get an expression which can be solved using Solve, but  solution contains  several Root objects.

Ulrich Neumann, I think you are correct... Thanks for the help!
